# When an Upstart Job is run, what is the value of $UPSTART_JOB set to?

Tags: upstart

I am working on moving a relatively large application that I haven't worked with very much from upstart to systemd in an effort to get it to run on a 16.04 system where it was previously running on 14.04. A few of the jobs call scripts that are checking for the value of $UPSTART_JOB. I need to figure out what to set this to so that I can manually set it in order to maintain compatibility with the scripts that are called until the scripts can be reworked later. What is this environment variable set to by Upstart? Is it just the name of the conf file or is there something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$UPSTART_JOB has the name of the invoked service module: the base of the config filename: foo.conf -> start foo -> echo $UPSTART_JOB -> 'foo'